# pr2 complete SLAM process

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-simulator, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm currently focusing on the way I can make a PR2 do SLAM in gazebo. I went through navigation stack tutorial, and pr2_2dnav_slam. The latter is quite interesting, but goals are still user-defined. So my question is : Does it exist an application doing autonomous SLAM i.e. making the robot explore his environment and decide which goals to reach to complete the map ?

I think it's doable using the simple_navigation_goals idea, but before spending time on that, I want to be sure I didn't miss something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32819/pr2-complete-slam-process/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [exploration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/exploration) stack in Bosch's repo. I haven't tried it, but it should provide the basic functionality that you request. At [Team Hector](http://www.gkmm.tu-darmstadt.de/rescue/) we have our own implementation of the exploration transform algorithm in use, but in the coming weeks I probably won't have time to make it fit for publishing.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1